# Pointing object reference to another object in Java

Tags: java

Let's say I have a `User` class (with properties like name, last name, etc.) and a `UserService` class that is used to query the database and get `User` data. Let's say I have the following method in my `UserService` class:

```
public User getUser(int userId)
{
    User user = new User();

    /* query database and returns user data. Then I use setters to set User data
    ...........
    */

    return user;
}
```

I have the following controller class:

```
public class DIGRCController {

    private User user;

    private UserService service;

    //getters and setters

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() { 

        service = new UserService();

        //imagine userId is coming from somewhere (not relevant to this question)
        user = service.getUser(userId);

    }

}
```

My question is:

Is `user = service.getUser(userId)` good practice?

`user` has one object reference and then I am pointing it to another reference. Is this ok in programming? If not, what should I do?

I checked a few questions in SO but couldn't find one with what I am looking for. If you have a SO question I could look at, please show me.

Comment: If I'm User #2, I get back User #1's data within that controller.

Comment: @Makoto I updated the question. For this question, is not relevant. I hard-coded a 1 there but in the real scenario it will be a variable.

Comment: What does 'user has one object reference and then I am pointing it to another reference' mean? What's so unusual about this code that you have to ask about it? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP it might be unclear to you but I didn't deserve a -1. What I am trying to ask is if it is fine for me to make an object reference point to another object reference. I am not an expert in OOP and was just wondering if that is okay. I feel the question was well asked. You could close it if you want but I didn't deserve the -1